# Where can I get `pngcrush` tool optimizes images for iOS and runnable on Linux server?

Tags: ios, optimization, png, pngcrush

iOS uses a variant of PNG processed a tool called `pngcrush`. If I want to optimized the images on Linux server, how can I do it?

Comment: @porneL How about post the comment as an answer? I want to choose it as the right answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore it, iOS-specific changes [don't improve performance](http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html). Use regular pngcrush or PNGOUT, AdvPNG.

Although ImageOptim (linked above) doesn't work on Linux, there's a [very similar](https://github.com/toy/image_optim) script for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This tool is named [pincrush](https://github.com/DHowett/pincrush).